# Site Responsivo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

É o seguinte, estou com dificuldades para modificar um rodapé em meu site. Estou usando Bostrap para dar estilo ao site, porém queria deixar o radapé em duas colunas em dispositivos moveis.

A estrutura do meu site é a seguinte:

CSS:

```css
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .footer-widget-container{
    /*display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;*/
    display:flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-align">
                    <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
                        <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Políticas</h4>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/como-comprar" class="nav-link">Como comprar?</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/como-vender" class="nav-link">Como vender?</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso" class="nav-link">Termo de Uso</a> </li>
                            <!--
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="/privacidade" class="nav-link">Política de Privacidade</a>
                </li>
                -->
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#politica-de-pagamento" class="nav-link">Política de Pagamento</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#politica-de-entrega" class="nav-link">Política de Entrega</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#trocas-devolucoes" class="nav-link">Política de Trocas e Devoluções</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
                        <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Institucional</h4>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/quem-somos" class="nav-link">Quem somos</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/curadores" class="nav-link">Curadores</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/imprensa" class="nav-link">Imprensa</a> </li>
                            <!--
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="/mapa-do-site" class="nav-link">Mapa do site</a>
                </li>
                -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
                        <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Atendimento</h4>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/#atendimento-telefone" class="nav-link open-lightbox">Via Telefone</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/#atendimento-chat" class="nav-link open-lightbox">Via Chat</a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="mailto:sac@freakmarket.com.br" class="nav-link">Via E-mail</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
                        <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Dúvidas</h4>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/ajuda" class="nav-link">F.A.Q.</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar a primeira div em uma coluna na esquerda e como colocar as outras três divs em uma unica coluna na direita.

Obrigado pela Atenção

Abraços!!!

Comment: Estou usando este modelo apenas para estudos

Comment: Na proxima vez informe a tecnologia usada, se não fica dificil ter certeza ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os números que estão nas classes col-**-* vão de 1 a 12.
Se queres dividir em duas colunas, você diz que cada div ocupará 6 partes. Se queres dividir em 3 colunas, você diz que a div ocupará 4 partes (4+4+4 = 12).
No caso para aplicar somente no mobile, você usa o col-xs-*

Para ocupar 2 colunas no mobile, você coloca a classe .col-xs-6, no exemplo abaixo terá 2 colunas principais, sendo a segunda coluna, dividida em 3.

```
<div class="footer-align">
    <div class="footer-widget col-xs-6 col-lg-2">
        <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Políticas</h4>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/como-comprar" class="nav-link">Como comprar?</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/como-vender" class="nav-link">Como vender?</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso" class="nav-link">Termo de Uso</a> </li>
            <!--<li class="nav-item"><a href="/privacidade" class="nav-link">Política de Privacidade</a></li>-->
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#politica-de-pagamento" class="nav-link">Política de Pagamento</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#politica-de-entrega" class="nav-link">Política de Entrega</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#trocas-devolucoes" class="nav-link">Política de Trocas e Devoluções</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-widget col-xs-6 col-lg-2">
        <div class="footer-widget col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Institucional</h4>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/quem-somos" class="nav-link">Quem somos</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/curadores" class="nav-link">Curadores</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/imprensa" class="nav-link">Imprensa</a> </li>
                <!--<li class="nav-item"><a href="/mapa-do-site" class="nav-link">Mapa do site</a></li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-widget col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Atendimento</h4>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/#atendimento-telefone" class="nav-link open-lightbox">Via Telefone</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/#atendimento-chat" class="nav-link open-lightbox">Via Chat</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="mailto:sac@freakmarket.com.br" class="nav-link">Via E-mail</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-widget col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Dúvidas</h4>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/ajuda" class="nav-link">F.A.Q.</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: R. Oliveira, muito obrigado pela resposta.

Infelizmente esta solução não funcionou, alguma outra parte do CSS devia estar sobrepondo o Boostrap. Eu fiz um "ajuste" funcionou da forma que fiz. Muito obrigado. Vou deixar a solução que consegui.

Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente a solução que o Givanildo me passou não funcionou comigo. Então o que fiz.

Foi o seguinte:

Clonei a class **footer-align** que é umas das classes da minha primeira coluna, o Coloquei a classe citada acima antes das classses **footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2** da segunda coluna de itens (Institucional).

O código ficou da seguinte maneira:

```css
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .footer-align {
    float: left;
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 40%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="footer-align">
  <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
    <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Políticas</h4>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/como-comprar" class="nav-link">Como comprar?</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/como-vender" class="nav-link">Como vender?</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso" class="nav-link">Termo de Uso</a> 
      </li>
      <!--
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="/privacidade" class="nav-link">Política de Privacidade</a>
                </li>
                -->
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#politica-de-pagamento" class="nav-link">Política de Pagamento</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#politica-de-entrega" class="nav-link">Política de Entrega</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/termos-de-uso#trocas-devolucoes" class="nav-link">Política de Trocas e Devoluções</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-align">
  <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
    <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Institucional</h4>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/quem-somos" class="nav-link">Quem somos</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/curadores" class="nav-link">Curadores</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/imprensa" class="nav-link">Imprensa</a> 
      </li>
      <!--
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="/mapa-do-site" class="nav-link">Mapa do site</a>
                </li>
                -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
    <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Atendimento</h4>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/#atendimento-telefone" class="nav-link open-lightbox">Via Telefone</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/#atendimento-chat" class="nav-link open-lightbox">Via Chat</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="mailto:sac@freakmarket.com.br" class="nav-link">Via E-mail</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-widget col-xs-3 col-lg-2">
    <h4 class="footer-widget__title">Dúvidas</h4>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="http://sandbox.freakmarket.com.br/ajuda" class="nav-link">F.A.Q.</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desta forma consegui o resultado que estava tentando alcançar.

Abraços!

Comment: Não use o trecho de código se não for para reproduzir o problema, trecho de código é para executar js+css+html, se for para apenas "mostrar" o código use o "Amostra de código" (é o botão com esse desenho `{ }`), entenda como se deve usar o trecho de código: **http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/3635** e **http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5640/3635**

Comment: Opa, desculpe.

Obrigado pela dica!!!